# Fedora, Android phone mounting?

Tags: fedora, mount, android

I am using Fedora 15 and I just plugged in my Samsung Vibrant Android phone, but my phone does not even give me the option to mount over USB like usual. It still charges though. Is there some configuration I need to do for Fedora?

Comment: Now it suddenly works so this may be some error not related to Fedora

Comment: Many phones expose their SD card over USB only when they're off (so that the PC and the phone aren't fighting over the contents). Maybe that's what you're observing?

Comment: @Gilles: Android phones can unmount their SD card to let the PC use it. It should ask the user whenever the USB cable is plugged in.

Comment: If you don't have any specyfic software under your Fedora, I strongly recommend you to install Fedora 20. With newer kernel, there are more drivers for Android devices.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo yum install libmtp

$ yum info libmtp
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, list-data, refresh-packagekit
Installed Packages
Name        : libmtp
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.1.6
Release     : 2.fc20
Size        : 480 k
Repo        : installed
Summary     : A software library for MTP media players
URL         : http://libmtp.sourceforge.net/
License     : LGPLv2+
Description : This package provides a software library for communicating with MTP
            : (Media Transfer Protocol) media players, typically audio players, video
            : players etc.
```

Also, you might want to look at the package `gvfs-mtp`.  I realize this question was asked some time ago, but it's upvoted twice without an answer; so, hopefully it'll be able to help someone since.